# save parsed JSON as obj

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

first question ever, I'm trying to parse a JSON file stored within the same file directory on my webhost as my html file that runs the javascript to parse it, I've added a console.log to debug and confrim that the file is being caught by the 'get' to ensure that I am  able to 'get' the file throgh the use of jquery getJSON, in the callback i've tried to create a function that re-defines a global variable as an object containing the parsed data, but when I try to inject it into a `document.getElemendtById('example').innerhtml = tgmindex.ToughGuys[1].name;`

it returns a error  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined"

here's my js/jquery

```html
var tgmIndex;
$(document).ready(function () {
$.getJSON("http://webspace.ocad.ca/~wk12ml/test.json",function(data){  
    console.log( "success" );
    
tgmIndex =$.parseJSON;   
    
document.getElementById('tgm1').innerHTML= tgmIndex.ToughGuys[1].name; 
});
});
```

and here is whats contained in the JSON (i made sure to try linting it first and it's a valid json)

`{"ToughGuys":[
    {"name":"Ivan", "position":"Executive"},
    {"name":"Little Johnny", "position":"Intern"},
    {"name":"Beige Cathy", "position":"Executive"},
    {"name":"Stan", "position":" original Intern"}
]}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably your service is returning `application/json`.  Therefore `data` already contains the json.

`tgmIndex = data;`

Then... "Tough Guys" is what you should be indexing. Not "ToughGuys"

Your example JSON is wrong in your question.  If I go to

http://webspace.ocad.ca/~wk12ml/test.json

I see:

```
{"Tough Guys":[
    {"name":"Ivan", "position":"Executive"},
    {"name":"Little Johnny", "position":"Intern"},
    {"name":"Beige Cathy", "position":"Executive"},
    {"name":"Stan", "position":"Intern 0"}
]}
```

See `"Tough Guys"`  There's your problem.

`document.getElementById('tgm1').innerHTML= tgmIndex['Tough Guys'][1].name;`

If `data` for some reason isn't JSON:

`tgmIndex = $.parseJSON(data);`

Comment: your suggestion returns the same new error as @crob 's response unfortunately

Comment: Wow I'm so happy you caught this! the version of the test.json was looking at while coding was corrected and I had forgotten to update the hosted version, you're a lifesaver!!!

Answer (score 1):

You're setting `tgmIndex` to the parseJson function.

Should be doing `tgmIndex =$.parseJSON(data);`

Comment: That still won't work since `data` is already an object, not JSON.

Comment: your suggestion returns a new Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

Comment: wich means it's looking at something it now sees as a string when i tries this and catches a single letter o , if it thinks it's undefined wich ive gotten from other attempts it returned the same with u for undefined as well